# Setting and passing a variable in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to set a variable in a jsp page, if it is a certain value, and then to test if it is there and then make a table row after a certain row. When I try it nothing happens.

```
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${regData}" varStatus='rowstatus'>
    <tr>
    <c:choose>

        <c:when test="${row.values[10]=='PROG'}">
            <c:set var="postTitle" value="Anttermin" scope="request"/>
        </c:when>
          </tr>
     </c:forEach>
         <c:if test="${fn:length(postTitle) == 'PROG'}">
            <tr>Anttermin</tr>
         </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${regData}" varStatus='rowstatus'>
    <tr>
    <c:choose>

        <c:when test="${row.values[10] eq 'PROG'}">
            <c:set var="postTitle" value="Anttermin" scope="request"/>
        </c:when>
          </tr>
     </c:forEach>
         <c:if test="${fn:length(postTitle) eq 'PROG'}">
            <tr>Anttermin</tr>
         </c:if>
```

For string you need to use `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: I tried that and got the following message: The function equals must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.

Comment: by the way the error throws for which of the 2 conditions?In your question I see to `==`.Also your code should have worked.Until you are passing some wrong variable

Comment: Now I don't get the error message, but I don't get any row with "Anttermin", either.

Answer (score 0):

Succeeded with following in the jsp

```
            </tr>
            <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${row.values[10] == 'PROG' && row.values[5] != 'AVBR'}">
            <tr>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}">Antagningstermin</td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}${style}">ANT</td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}">${row.values[8]}</td>
            <td class="tableCell${cellStyle}"></td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
        </c:choose>
```